# Website works remotely but not on the server itself when called by domain

Tags: iis, windows-server

I am using Windows Server 2019 and in IIS 10 I have created a website and I have bound it to both: "localhost" and "mydomain.com" on port 80.

mydomain.com works correctly from any client but on the server only when I call "localhost" it works otherwise I get the following error (when called by domain):

[image]

Comment: What kind of authentication is used, and is it a question of authentication, so the server can only be accessed through localhost, not through mydomain.com?

Comment: I have this exact same problem. I just created some sites in IIS (multiple domains). All work as expected if connecting from a remote machine, but I get connection refused if I try and connect locally from the Win 2019 server (both Firefox and IE). The server can access the internet fine and can load other web pages from the browser on the server.

Comment: @Nathan I found the answer on another StackExchange site (I think it was the webmasters), it was said that this is something normal and instead of calling the domain name I should use https://localhost on the server and I went with this approach, I hope this would also solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

Configure your DNS in your local server to resolve the domain name as localhost

Answer (score 2):

On clients, your request domain.com is resolved by its configured DNS.
It can be on public DNS (internet) or private ones (company, intranet).

From the server domain.com, do you have access to the same DNS than your clients use ?

If not, either configure additional DNS servers :
https://serverspace.io/support/help/configuring-a-dns-server-on-windows-server-2012-or-later/

or you could edit you `Host` file of mydomain.com (local DNS):
`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

It may look like that :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   mydomain.com

# and existing settings
```